# Rails - Show A Random Record But Not The Current

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, random-access

At the end of a blog post I would like to display a teaser link to another random post. Obviously this link should be NOT a teaser for the current post itself.

I figured already out how to choose a random post, but there is still the chance that the teaser link is a link to the current post. I couldn't figure out, how can I exclude this case.

Here is my controller:

```
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @staff_pickrandom = Post.where(staff_pick:true).order("RANDOM()").limit(1)
end
```

I am quite new to Rails and I am still struggling with basic stuff.
Sorry, if this is an easy one. Thank you so much for helping out!!!

UPDATE:
I am using Rails 3.2 and the ["friendly_id" Gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `order('RANDOM()').limit(1)` is the right way to start since it is better to let the DB choose a random record, than fetching a large set of ids, and letting Ruby sample from an array.  In order to avoid choosing the post you are currently on use `where.not` to exclude that post

```
 Post.where(staff_pick: true).where.not(id: @post.id).order('RANDOM()').limit(1)
```

or

```
 Post.where(staff_pick: true).where('id != ?', @post.id).order('RANDOM()').limit(1)
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer. I tried your solution, but unfortunately I get an error:  ArgumentError in PostsController#show -
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Comment: I'll try shortly , try wrapping RANDOM() in double quotes

Comment: Thanks again! Really appreciated! Double quotes unfortunately doesn't fix it.

Comment: What's your @post set to? Can you inspect it.

Comment: What do you mean with "set to"? Which "id"? (By the way: I am using the 'friendly_id' Gem, could this make any trouble?)

Comment: doubt it (unless you are using 4.0) as of 5.0 "Finders are no longer overridden by default" and from your question you are using `Post.find`, not `Post.friendly.find`. The above does work on my local test using my own project e.g. `User.where(status: 'active').where.not(id: @user.id).order("RANDOM()").limit(1)`.  So I can only presume @post may be nil?

Comment: Blotto, I am using Rails 3.2 - That's why "where.not" doesn't work?

Comment: I am using friendly_id (4.0.10.1). 5.0 seems to be Rails 4 only.

Comment: so what does @post look like? show the output of `p @post.inspect`

Answer (score 0):

```
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id]) # [1]
    ids = Post.ids # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    ids.shuffle # [3, 5, 2, 1, 4]
    ids.delete(params[:id]) # [3, 5, 2, 4]
    @staff_pickrandom = Post.find(ids[0]) # [3]
end
```

there is many way to do that. It's better to create a helper.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am struggling with your solution, cause I use this "where(staff_pick:true)" part. The random post is chosen not out of an array of all posts, but just out of a selection of posts.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how large you want the set to be. The easiest is:

```
@staff_pickrandom = Post.where(staff_pick:true).sample
```

That will pick a random object from the array returned by `Post.where(staff_pick:true)`. If you find that is too many records then you can add more into the where clauses

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions. Looks good, but I get an error. Not sure, why:  

NoMethodError in Posts#show
undefined method `each' for #<Post:0x00000109d00a98> - (If I use my controller see above, everything works fine)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@post = Post.where(staff_pick: true).where.not(id: params[:id]).shuffle.first
```

If `where.not` can't be done like in Rails 4, try:

```
Post.where(staff_pick: true).where("id != ?", params[:id]).shuffle.first
```

Edit: since you're using friendly_id gem, you shouldn't compare the slug (params[:id]) to a recorded id in database.
First declare which post you're looking for like `@post = Post.find(params[:id])` and remove params[:id] from the queries above and use `@post.id` instead.

I guess that should work!

Comment: Diego, thanks! I am using Rails 3.2, so I tried your second suggestion. Unfortuntaly I get this error:  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PostsController#show
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "a-dummy-post-with-all-elements"

Comment: I am using the 'friendly_id' Gem. Could this be the reason for the error?

Comment: Yeah... totally. Let me try to write something else. One sec.

Comment: Try declaring the post as a instance variable before, and using it's id. I've updated the answer.