# show different record with order('RANDOM()')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, random

I'm trying to show a random record in my index view upon on reload, but I want that record to be different than the current one. In my Word model, words have terms, which are what I'm trying to display (i.e. with `<%= @word.term %>`. I've been trying to implement the answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836885/rails-show-a-random-record-but-not-the-current) post, but they're not working.

Currently, this shows random records, but will repeat the current one on occasion:

```
def index
  @word = Word.order("RANDOM()").first
end
```

If I try

```
def index
  @word = Word.where("id != ?", params[:id]).shuffle.first
end
```

I see `undefined method 'term' for nil:NilClass`. How can I implement the random order while avoiding a repeated record on reload?

Comment: Are you passing `id` to the index action? can you show us how you build the url? Could you put the "current" word into session instead?

Comment: @TarynEast What I have above is the entire index action as I currently have it. I was accessing the page at /words. For this initial testing, I've just added a few words in the database from the console. (I'm not clear on what putting the current word into session entails). I appreciate the help.

Comment: where do you create the URL for the index action (in your view?) what does the resulting url look like? if you don't put the `:id` of the "current word" into that, then your controller can't then find it by using `params(:id)`

Comment: You params[:id] is nil, so your request return an empty array []. [].first = nil  => you have an error. Ensure that you add the proper parameter in your url.